# Automated tests for Java Swing GUIs

Tags: java, swing, testing, automated-tests

What options are there for building automated tests for GUIs written in Java Swing?

I'd like to test some GUIs which have been written using the [NetBeans Swing GUI Builder](http://www.netbeans.org/features/java/swing.html), so something that works without requiring special tampering of the code under test would be ideal.

Comment: related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79891/what-is-the-best-testing-tool-for-swing-based-applications

Comment: I recommend trying ReTest (https://www.retest.de/en/), which implements an interesting new approach to functional regression testing combined with ai-based monkey testing.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Recently I came across FEST which seemed promising, except that the developer [announced in 2012 that development would not continue](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/easytesting/bAt1nWx55FM/e3DF0bxGUf8J).

[AssertJ](https://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/) is a fork of FEST that is working very well for me. It is actively maintained (at time of writing), supports Java 8, has assertions for a few popular libraries such as Guava and Joda Time, and is very well documented. It is also free and open.

Comment: Can this be used to automate third party Java applications without access to the source code? If so, how?

Comment: @StevenVascellaro looks it cannot, anyways +1 for AssertJ Swing

Comment: How are you identifying the object properties. My application under test  is a Java Swing UI. How do I get the properties of target fields/buttons that are to be automated?

Comment: You can use Testmate to automate Java swing application for free
https://youtu.be/BQQdJ0V23GM

Answer (score 26):

I'm currently using [FEST](http://code.google.com/p/fest/).  It works with JUnit and will also take screenshots of failed tests.

It has default component hunting methods which look for the name of the component being tested (which need to be set manually), but you can also generate the testers for a given component by passing it the component.

Comment: It moves in GitHub from [this post](http://fest.easytesting.org/archives/167).

Comment: Fest swing is not being developed any more. It does not support java 7 either. Seems like the swing part of fest is totally dead!

Comment: I use FEST with Swing in Java7 just fine. See https://github.com/bitcoin-solutions/multibit-hd/tree/develop/mbhd-swing/src/test/java/org/multibit/hd/ui/fest for comprehensive test scenarios

Comment: The Fest project web site is gone (http://fest.easytesting.org). The documentation in 2015 is pretty lacking. Is there anything else like it that drives a Swing UI?

Comment: As someone unfamiliar with JUnit, how can I find and control a Java applet with FEST?

Comment: @StevenVascellaro Your best bet would be to ask a separate question, I don't do applet development.

Answer (score 14):

You can try to use [Cucumber](http://cukes.info) and [Swinger](http://github.com/demetriusnunes/swinger) for writing functional acceptance tests in plain english for Swing GUI applications. Swinger uses Netbeans' Jemmy library under the hood to drive the app.

Cucumber allows you to write tests like this:

```
 Scenario: Dialog manipulation
    Given the frame "SwingSet" is visible
      And the frame "SwingSet" is the container
    When I click the menu "File/About"
    Then I should see the dialog "About Swing!"
    Given the dialog "About Swing!" is the container
    When I click the button "OK"
    Then I should not see the dialog "About Swing!"
```

Take a look at this [Swinger video demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YCLsXka_QvA) to see it in action.

Answer (score 9):

We are considering  [jemmy](https://jemmy.java.net/) to automate some of the GUI testing. Looks promising.

Comment: Jemmy is a very solid framework and we are using it since more than 5 years very successfully.

Answer (score 8):

I use `java.awt.Robot`.  Is not nice, is not easy but works every time.

Pros:

- You are in control
- Very fast
- Build your own FWK
- Portable
- No external dependencies

Cons:

- No nice GUI to build test
- You have to leave the GUI alone while you test
- Build your own FWK
- Difficult to change test code and create your first harness

Now if you have the budget I would go for LoadRunner. Best in class.

(Disclosure: relationship to the company that owns LR, but I worked with LR before the relationship)

Comment: You say "build your own FWK". What is a FWK?

Comment: From my experience, I can say that AWT's `Robot` is extremely brittle. A major issue is that its low level [API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) is working with absolute coordinates. Tests may break even if your system under test (SUT) hasn't changed (e.g. when executed on another OS).

Answer (score 7):

We're using [QF-Test](http://www.qfs.de/en/qftest/index.html) and are quite satisfied.

Answer (score 6):

I haven't used it personally, but [SwingUnit](https://swingunit.dev.java.net/) looks quite good. You can use it with jUnit, and it isn't based on "location of components" (i.e. x and y co-ordinates).

The only thing you may have to do with the NetBeans GUI Builder is set unique names for your components.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [**Marathon**](http://marathontesting.com/) :
"Marathon Integrated Testing Environment, MarathonITE, is an affordable, easy-to-use and cross-platform Java/Swing™ GUI Test automation framework. You can use MarathonITE‘s inbuilt script recorder to create clean, readable test scripts either in Python or Ruby. Advanced features like extract-method refactoring, create-datadriven-tests and objectmap editing allows you to create maintainable, resilient test suites."

Answer (score 3):

Sikuli: a GUI-tester using screenshots
http://sikuli.org/

Comment: Note that it is http://www.sikulix.com/ nowadays (still open source)

Answer (score 3):

You could try [ReTest](https://www.retest.de/en/), which is a novel tool that implements an innovative approach to functional regression testing and combines it with ai-based monkey testing. It is about to become open source as well...

Disclaimer: I am one of the founders of the company behind ReTest.

Answer (score 2):

For those with an adventurous mind, there is gooey https://github.com/robertoaflores/Gooey a (very basic and under-development) programmatic testing tool for swing applications.

Answer (score 1):

Just did some quick scans. [Squish](http://www.froglogic.com/squish/gui-testing/editions/java.php) was the most promising. Not for free though

Answer (score 1):

You can user [sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/) or [Automa](http://www.getautoma.com/) for testing your GUI part, these are well documented and tested tools