# Unit-testing of visual components in Java

Tags: java, unit-testing, user-interface

Assume that we have some simple Java visual component, for example, rectangle. Component can change position (let it be changePosition(int x, int y) method) and color (changeColor(Color color)). How can I create unit -test for such component?

This is extremely simple situation, but, I think, it is nice illustration for my question: how we can create unit-test for any visual component in Java?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/91179/automated-tests-for-java-swing-guis

Comment: I don't have any experience with it, but the [approval test library](http://approvaltests.sourceforge.net/) could very much be able to help you here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly doubt, that a *component can change its position* or *change its color*. Components have *properties* that are used by rendering engines to display them on a screen.

A visual component is some sort of *model* for something that we see on a display.

So when we call `changePosition(x,y)` on a component, then we usually alter field values on the component instance. And we only have to (unit-)test, if those fields have the expected values after we called `changePosition(x,y)`.

Comment: Say I have a drawable object with draw(graphics)/getColor()/setColor(color), I want to test that the draw call will draw a red object whenever I have done setColor(Color.Red). This isn't the same as checking getColor().equals(Color.Red). It requires more than that, for example the unit test calling the draw() method with a mock graphics that actually detects the object actually drawing itself with the required color. Way more difficult than testing that mutating an object actually mutates it...

Comment: So we can only test model of component? And if we try to test View of this component we should create complex mock-object with draw method which can check actual view of component. Am I right?

Comment: @Anders - if you want to *unit test* a `paint(Graphics g)` implementation, then you could pass an image type graphics and verify, that the painted image is as expected (If you really want to do that).

Comment: @Andreas, That is one possibility. Feels a bit difficult to do image recognition though, I'd probably settle with testing mockGraphics.getThingsDrawn().count() == 1 and its color is red so on. 
Lampapos:, what we are tryinhg to say is that it is difficult to test how something *looks*, you can ask something how it (thinks) it looks easily, but that is only almost the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

I would write up a test that creates a suitable `BufferedImage`, retrieve that image's graphics context and instruct the component (under test) to `paint()` on that.

Then I could perform some assertions on the rendered image, such as checking if a particular pixel/region is in the desired color.