# Java Swing UI test driver replacement for Fest

Tags: java

Is there a replacement for Fest, such that the replacement could drive a Java Swing UI in a blackbox manner (not JUnit) and enable BDD? Fest (https://code.google.com/p/fest/, http://fest.easytesting.org) has been abandoned since 2013 (https://github.com/alexruiz/fest-swing-1.x) as given by its GitHub project.

Java BDD tools such as cucumber (https://cucumber.io) and jbehave (http://jbehave.org) allow JUnit whitebox style, high-level integration testing, but do not drive the Swing UI from the outside in a blackbox manner.

Switching the UI from Swing to JavaFX is not an option due to human resource constraints.

The current related question is behind the times

[Automated tests for Java Swing GUIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91179/automated-tests-for-java-swing-guis)

Comment: You can use Testmate to automate Java swing application for free
https://youtu.be/BQQdJ0V23GM

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[AssertJ Swing](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/assertj-swing.html) is a fork from FEST and seems to be currently updated. 
[Jubula](http://www.eclipse.org/jubula/) from Eclipse and  [Marathon](https://sourceforge.net/projects/marathonman/) are other open source options.

[MarathonITE](https://marathontesting.com/) adds bells and whistles to Marathon, comes with support and a proprietary license .

I am aware that this is an old question, but since it comes up when I search for Java Swing functional test automation, I hope this is useful for someone else.

Comment: You can use Testmate to automate Java swing application for free
https://youtu.be/BQQdJ0V23GM

Answer (score 1):

UISpec4J (http://www.uispec4j.org/) seems to be an option, I can't say much because just discovered it.

Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

ReTest (https://www.retest.de/en/) also is an option. It implements an innovative approach to functional regression testing and combines this with ai-based monkey testing. There will also soon be an open source version.

Disclaimer: I am one of the founders of the company behind ReTest.