# How to automate Java Web start application?

Tags: java, automated-tests, java-web-start

I have to automate a JWS application (with *.jnlp extension) . We cannot automate the same using selenium as it is an windows type application. I also tried with AutoIt but it is not able to capture element properties using the same.

Could anyone please help how can I automate this application .I am trying to automate JWS application for the first time.

Answer (score 1):

QTP and TestComplete are very good to automate Java desktop applications. I am using QTP currently to automate Calypso (a java application) and it works perfectly. I've used TestComplete previously to automate similar Java desktop application. They both are paid software, but well worth it if you want to automate complex applications.

Comment: Thanks Pankaj for the information . I need to automate Java web start swing application. Could you please tell me if I can automate this using TestComplete tool . If yes , do you have any idea where I can get more information on this .As I am trying to automate JWS application for the first time and I have not worked on TestComplete tool previously.

Comment: @PriyankaAgarwal - Yes, you can use either of them to automate Java apps. I would recommend you download their software (trail period is 1 month) and see which would be the easiest to use. QTP and TestComplete uses VBScript to automate. However, TestComplete supports other languages too like JavaScript, C# etc if you are comfortable in them.

Answer (score -2):

Swing applications can be automated using [SWTBot][1]. Its an open source alternative to automate swing applications. This requires understanding of Swing framework and controls.

[1]: http://www.eclipse.org/swtbot/ 
EDIT: Maybe any of this can help for testing swing applications: [Automated tests for Java Swing GUIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91179/automated-tests-for-java-swing-guis)

Comment: I am working on JWS application . Could we automate this using SWTBot tool . Which language does it support.

Comment: Language: Java..BeAware..This requires knowledge of Swing technology

Comment: SWTBot can automate SWT-based applications, not Swing ones.

Comment: maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/91179/automated-tests-for-java-swing-guis