# Gephi automation: how to make multiple graphs at once

Tags: graph, gephi

I am looking for a tool to automate making graphs with Gephi. I have dozens of similar graphs to prepare (only labels and figures in data differ), so need something able to automatically:

- load nodes and edges from a file (e.g., csv)
- set up layout (e.g., "type='force atlas 2', iterations=n, threads=m, scaling=p, gravity=q...")
- apply selected laoyut
- tune appearance (ranking: color, size)
- export graph

I am aware of [Gephi Toolkit](https://gephi.org/toolkit/), but it is for Java. Maybe there is some other way to automate Gephi? (or I will have to learn Java, which is not bad, but requires time)

I've also found [Gephi Scripting Plugin](https://github.com/gephi/gephi/wiki/Scripting-Plugin), which is good but lacks some features, e.g. can't set up layout (only runs it with default settings).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you write in Python?

Comment: Yes, I do write in Python.

Comment: This thread might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/91179/automated-tests-for-java-swing-guis

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit tricky and haven't tried myself but if you don't want to get your feet wet with Java then you could try one of the automation frameworks that allow you to control a GUI application, e.g. [Robot](http://robotframework.org/), [PyAutoGUI](https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui) or if you use Windows you can use [pywinauto](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pywinauto/).

I know it not a complete answer but it might give you a lead.

Comment: I've installed Gephi. As I can see, it's SunAWT application. I'm not aware of any automation tools that are able to automate it out of Java. If you know such a tool please let me know. BTW, even Windows UI Automation API cannot see GUI controls on Gephi dialogs.

Comment: Of course, you can write some resolution-dependent things like `app.Dialog.ClickInput(coords=(32, 120))` but it's not well portable if you use it on several machines. And it's not readable enough.