# Testing a client-server based app in Java

Tags: java, swing, testing, client-server

I have written a client server based application in Java, where the client continually (after every 30 seconds) sends some data, and a panel on server is redrawn according to the incoming message from client. There are multiple threads (one for redrawing, one for reading incoming messages, and one for outgoing messages) running on the server. For GUI I have used Swing.

Now I am a complete newbie in testing, and I would like to know various methods, tricks and gotchas for testing my application. Any web resource or good texts on the same will be very helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not better distribute your compiled stuff to as many people as you can, and use it with them, that will let you know your bugs (if any). Or you referring to something like [VTune Performance Analyzer](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-vtune-amplifier-xe/)

Comment: but i want to test before it reaches out to people.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look to [Maveryx](http://www.maveryx.com) test automation framework and its documentation. It contains several examples to create and run automated scripts for testing Java (swing-based) applications.

Comment: I didn't knew about such tools for Java :-) +1 for this information.

Answer (score 2):

You will, at least, have to do testing at two levels.

1. You will need to first unit test your java code, on both server and client, by writing e.g. [JUnit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JUnit) tests.
2. You should then test the server and the client components individually by simulating the other side. Something like [JMock](http://www.jmock.org/) may be able to help you simulate the parts of the code that you are not testing. For testing you GUI, you may refer to [What is the best testing tool for Swing-based applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79891/what-is-the-best-testing-tool-for-swing-based-applications)

There is a lot of good material available on this topic online!

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking to do unit testing, one of the most common ways of doing this in Java is with JUnit.  The JUnit Cookbook has some decent information to get started with writing your unit tests.

[JUnit Cookbook](http://junit.sourceforge.net/doc/cookbook/cookbook.htm)